# Difference between UTC Time values scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I would like to perform difference between UTC current time and a UTC value in scala.

Comment: what do you mean by difference betweeen `UTC` now and `UTC` value?? scala uses java time api `ZonedDateTime.now`

Comment: What type/format is the "UTC value"? Please give an example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
import java.time._

val time1 = Instant.parse("2017-01-01T12:00:00Z")
val time2 = Instant.now()

val diff = Duration.between(time1, time2)

println("Difference is " + diff)

println("or in seconds: " + diff.getSeconds())
```

[Try it here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7lhGZCqdTFCBZpP4eKqGfg)

Further reading:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html

Comment: Is this UTC ? im getting UTC value something like this from Postgres Table as "2017-08-17 14:09:03.652+00" and in Database its defined as "timestamp" with utc format

Comment: You need to clarify what connection library you are using. What Scala type does your value currently come back as? My example is UTC, yes, but I don't think that means what you think it means. UTC is just the name of a timezone, not a datetime string format or a Scala class. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time